# This script to create and read a mysql record won't run

Tags: python, mysql

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import MySQLdb 


db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','tekno','poop','media')

cursor = db.cursor()

data = cursor.fetchone()

sql = """ INSERT INTO shows_and_tv(watched_on,title,score_rating(curtime(),"mega","20")"""
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
    except:
        db.rollback()

try:
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        date1 = row[0]
        name  = row[1]
        score = row[2]
        print 'date1'

db.close()
```

I keep getting a syntax error at the close() and I'm not sure what the problem is.

It just says syntax error column 2

I'm using komodo edit and when i switch the language to python from python 3, thats when the error shows up.

In python3 it's clear but when i run it i get the error in the same place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

string literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`). Numbers are denoted as bare literals. So:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO shows_and_tv(watched_on,title,score_rating(curtime(),'mega',20)"""
```